# New android project with Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm getting started with phonegap and I don't know more about this.how can I create a new android project with the Phonegap in the Eclips platform.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Project with Command-Line as written on [Phonegap Webpage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage), e.g:
your Cordova Folder is in `C:\cordova` and Project in `C:\Project`. Open Command Line and type

```
C:\cordova\bin\create C:\Project com.something.myprojectname YourProjectName
```

and add it to your workspace in Eclipse. Right-click in `Package Explorer`, choose `New->Other...->Android Project from Existing Code` and browse your Project Folder.

Answer (score 0):

First, download Apache Cordova last version : [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/index.html#download)

Second, install android SDK [Android sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

If you use eclipse, DO NOT use Eclipse ADT (which is included into ADT bundle you just installed) because it doesn't have web developing tools.

Instead, use [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) - php development tools) which includes all you need for web development, and install the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) into it for supporting android projects

Then you simply create an android project following this [cordova quickstart](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) until you create the project.

Into it, there will be a "www" folder with an index.
Just build your app in this folder like any web project.

An alternative would be using a cloud IDE like [Icenium](http://www.icenium.com/) (that's what I do) which creates the phonegap project for you in one click, and you can run it on your phone with a USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

1. Include cordova-x-y-z.jar in your project
2. Extend your MainActivity class from DroidGap instead of Activity
3. create a folder "www" in folder "assets"
4. create index.html in "www"
5. In your MainActivityclass, replace the call loadContentView() by super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Hope it helps